# Automating Microsoft Access with C# instead of VB6

Tags: c#, ms-access, vba

Is there a version of Microsoft Office Access uses C# instead of VB6 for native automation?  If so how do I go about using it - is there some way to switch it or activate it?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean Access, the rapid application database development tool, or Jet/ACE, the default database use by Access?

Comment: Yep that's the one - Microsoft Access.

Comment: No. Why would you do that ? Triple the development duration ? 8-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natively, no. But here is an article on how to do some basic automation functions externally using C#:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317114

It's not integration in the sense that you can write macros in it, but it will give you a reasonable level of control.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I did see that article, but was hoping that MS had integrated .net by now.  I seem to remember checking a box when installing that said something about using .net for automation. sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but it's not like flipping a switch on and off.
[Automating Access with C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317114)

Comment: If you're using COM automation, you're not really using C# for your code, no? Or, put another way, you're writing Access code (i.e., VBA, executed via COM) inside C#, and at a couple levels removed.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help:

- [How to automate Microsoft Access by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317114)

Another article for MS Access and C# connection:

- [Simple Movie Database in C# using Microsoft Access](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/simple_movie_database.aspx)